# completely remove vscode and reinstall to default

Tags: visual-studio-code

### My c++ compiler is not working

I am having trouble with vscode c++ compiler so  I need to completely remove vscode to re install from scratch.
can you help please.
I have installed mingw and set correct envirment path.
The only way I can solve the problem is to start from scratch

Comment: VSC does not have a c++ compiler so no need to uninstall it.

Comment: g++ is not working and none of the compiling features work in vs code although i have g++ version g++ (MinGW.org GCC Build-2) 9.2.0 installed on my computer

Comment: get g++ to work on the command line outside VSC. VSC just creates a shell and executes a command.

Comment: I have tried compiling cmd shell typing g++ -o main main.cpp but it does compile to main.exe but when I execute program it says Access is denied and  I had to unhide main.exe file through properties. do you think there is a problem with mingw download.

Comment: you need to follow the c++ docs of VSC to the letter if you want to debug the C++ program. You get very strange behavior if you don't do this. `g++ not working` is very vague. What do you try and what is the responds? Edit your question, comments are not suited for this